# Combine the queries in sql-server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables Ward_Master and IP_Admission, and i have these three queries which is specified below

```
  select Ward_ID ,ward_name,bed_strength from Ward_Master
  select * from IP_Admission where Ward_ID=1;
  SELECT M.Bed_Strength - COUNT(A.WARD_id)  as Free_Bed
  FROM IP_Admission A  
 JOIN  Ward_Master M ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID 
  WHERE (A.Status='V' OR A.Status='D') and M.Ward_ID=1 group by M.Bed_Strength;
```

Which will give the output as

```
 Ward_ID   Ward_Name       Bed_Strengh
   1    Labor           6
   2    GYN         6
   3    OBG         6
   4    High Risk   6
   5    PED         14
   6    PNC         14
   7    Special         11
   8    Deluxe          2
   9    OPT-M           8
   10   OPT-F           7 

   IP_NO    Ward_ID Status
   IP001    1        V
   IP002    1        O
   IP003    1        D


    Free_Bed
     4
```

As you can see the output of these queries resembles only for ward_Id = 1.I need the output some what like

```
    Ward_ID   Ward_Name       Bed_Strengh   Free_Bed
   1    Labor           6                  4 
   2    GYN         6               //Free bed for ward_id=2
   3    OBG         6               //Free bed for ward_id=3 
   4    High Risk   6                 so on....   
   5    PED         14
   6    PNC         14
   7    Special         11
   8    Deluxe          2
   9    OPT-M           8
   10   OPT-F           7
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question but does this help:

```
SELECT M.Ward_ID, M.Bed_Strength - ISNULL(COUNT(A.WARD_id),0)  as Free_Bed
FROM Ward_Master M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
IP_Admission A  
ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID 
AND (A.Status='V' OR A.Status='D')
GROUP BY M.Ward_ID, M.Bed_Strength;
```

Comment: One conflict occurs if count is zero then the row is not getting displayed.

Comment: I will change my answer based on your feedback